# BITCOIN URI BIP72

Tags: uri, bitcoin, cryptoapi

Разбираюсь на данный момент с такой вещью как Bitcoin URI, есть разные форматы генерации адреса к примеру

`bitcoin:mqVhPx7b4P2snRRY66ambvVRpnWLyDZVwT?amount=0.001`

С таким адресом все понятно, вставляешь этот адрес например в electrum, автоматически подставляются все значения и пользователь не может изменить размер платежа. Но есть еще адрес вот такого характера

`bitcoin:?r=https://some.url/12345678`

На сколько я понимаю, вставляя в кошелек такой адрес, кошелек шлет запрос на сервер отбработчик, а обработчик в виде ответа присылает данные о платеже 
`amoun, address, message etc`

Подскажите плиз как обрабатывать такой запрос, может хедеры нужны какие, может структура обработанного массива должна быть правильной, что именно я должен сделать на своей стороне что бы пользователю выставить счет?

Comment: Так берете официальную спецификацию, там всё написано. https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0072.mediawiki

Comment: @Zergatul Читал и не увидел что я должен возвращать.

Comment: Там написано: `This BIP describes an extension to the bitcoin: URI scheme (BIP 21) to support the payment protocol (BIP 70).` А теперь читайте BIP70 спецификацию :) там как раз про все сообщения между кастомером и мерчантом https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0070.mediawiki

Comment: @Zergatul все как обычно, смотришь в книгу, видишь фигу) По тихоньку начинаю въезжать, огромное спасибо=)